# Start XAMPP Control Panel's MySQL and Apache

Tags: c#

Is it possible to Start XAMPP Control Panel's MySQL and Apache by a button click using C# ?

thanks in advance..

Comment: Can they be started from the command line?  Then yes, you can invoke a command line execution from just about any programming language.

Comment: a simple solution : go to C:/xampp , you will find all services related to xampp , and all of them have their start and stop bat files. like : apache_start.bat, mysql_start.bat and so on. Just execute the cmd with the bat files and they will start. That's an easy process using Process.Start

Answer (score 0):

I think an easy way is this:

- Set Appache and MySQL to start with XAMPP Panel ([XMPP Panel -> Options -> Autostart of modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnf6n.png)
- Make a WinForm application
- Add a button on it
- Add a click event to the button (called `startMySqlAndAppache_Click`)
  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V022v.png)
- Double click on the button
- Change the opened file to be identical with `Form1.cs`:

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace XAMPP_starter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string _xamppPanelPath;

        public Form1()
        {
            // Your absolute path to the XAMPP panel (for eg.:)
            _xamppPanelPath = @"C:\xampp\xampp-control.exe";

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void startMySqlAndAppache_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Start the XAMPP Panel with this code
            Process.Start(_xamppPanelPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: owwww thanks for that idea. but where can i found the exact path of XAMPP ?

Comment: It's alway in C:/xampp